# Hashing the password in ASP.NET Core Web API controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to write the code for hashing the password in an ASP.NET Core Web API controller. When I try to use reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` it has already deprecated. I am using .NET 6 version. I am looking for a solution how to replace  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` with new one.

Here is the my code:

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Persistance.Repository;

namespace NewsAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserRepo _userrepo;
        private readonly IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> _passwordHasher;

        public UserController(IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> passwordHasher, IUserRepo userrepo)
        {
            _userrepo = userrepo;
            _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        }

        [HttpGet("login")]
        public User AuthenticateLogin(string userName, string password)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user =  _userrepo.GetUser(userName, password);
            string hashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(null, password);
            return user;
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]       
        public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core Identity or not? If you are, then you shouldn't be hashing passwords by yourself: ASP.NET Core Identity handles that for you. As for the deprecated reference, please tell us the **exact** message you're seeing, because ASP.NET Core Identity is certainly not deprecated.